# Replace column in CSV file with one-minute interval timestamps

Tags: bash, awk

I have a CSV file with a timestamp and some data values:

```
 1455840000,76.357,899.500,326.717,8.000
 1455840060,76.490,899.650,326.150,8.000
 ...etc
```

But I want to replace the timestamp column with new timestamp values. The last row should be the current time, and all prior rows should be one minute earlier than the row after it.

How can I do this with a shell script, e.g. bash/awk?

Comment: How do we know the `start` and `end` timestamps? Where do we start and end?

Comment: @Inian the end timestamp is the current time. Then iterating in reverse order to the start of the file in one minute decrements. The file can be any length so we don't know the start timestamp apart from by counting back the number of rows.

Comment: When you said _Then iterating in reverse order to the start of the file_, what defines the _start_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the file content using `tac`, do operation, and then reverse back to original sequence:

```
tac file.txt | \
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{"date +%s"|getline cur; $1=cur; print; next}; \
              {$1=cur-(60*(NR-1)); print}' | tac
```

- For the (reversed) first line, we get the current timestamp in epoch, and save it in a variable `cur`
- For the next lines, we subtract each line by `60 * (line number - 1)` seconds to get required times

Note that, the time calculation might not be precise as you can imagine.

**Example:**

```
% cat ts.txt 
1455840000,76.357,899.500,326.717,8.000
1455840060,76.490,899.650,326.150,8.000
1455840000,76.357,899.500,326.717,8.000
1455840060,76.490,899.650,326.150,8.000

% tac ts.txt | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==1{"date +%s"|getline cur; $1=cur; print; next}; {$1=cur-(60*(NR-1)); print}' | tac
1475497096,76.357,899.500,326.717,8.000
1475497156,76.490,899.650,326.150,8.000
1475497216,76.357,899.500,326.717,8.000
1475497276,76.490,899.650,326.150,8.000
```

Comment: Per my comment on Aaron's answer, there's no indication in the Q that the OP is running an operating system likely to include `tac`, so I mentioned some alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want:

```
$ cat file
1455840000,76.357,899.500,326.717,8.000
1455840060,76.490,899.650,326.150,8.000
1455840000,76.357,899.500,326.717,8.000
1455840060,76.490,899.650,326.150,8.000
1455840000,76.357,899.500,326.717,8.000
1455840060,76.490,899.650,326.150,8.000
```

With GNU awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; now=systime()} NR>FNR{$1 = now - (NR-2*FNR)*60; print}' file file
1475504973,76.357,899.500,326.717,8.000
1475505033,76.490,899.650,326.150,8.000
1475505093,76.357,899.500,326.717,8.000
1475505153,76.490,899.650,326.150,8.000
1475505213,76.357,899.500,326.717,8.000
1475505273,76.490,899.650,326.150,8.000
```

With other awks:

```
$ awk -v now=$(date +'%s') 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>FNR{$1 = now - (NR-2*FNR)*60; print}' file file
1475504973,76.357,899.500,326.717,8.000
1475505033,76.490,899.650,326.150,8.000
1475505093,76.357,899.500,326.717,8.000
1475505153,76.490,899.650,326.150,8.000
1475505213,76.357,899.500,326.717,8.000
1475505273,76.490,899.650,326.150,8.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it :

```
tac inputFile | awk -v ts="$(date +%s)" -v OFS=, -F, '{ $4 = strftime("%c", ts - NR * 60) ; print $0 }' | tac
```

`tac` reverse the input file so that we can compute the dates from the only known value, the current date. We'll revert it back after we have processed every line.

`awk`'s `-v` flag gives us the ability to use a variable, so we let `bash` compute the current timestamp and pass it to `awk` as an unix timestamp (number of seconds since 01/01/1970).

`awk`'s `-F` flag specifies the column separator.

Then at each line, the last column is replaced by the given timestamp minus 60 seconds for each line previously read, which we display in an human-readable format with strftime.

Example :

```
$ cat inputFile
a,b,c,d
a1,b1,c1,d1
a2,b2,c2,d2

$ tac inputFile | awk -v ts="$(date +%s)" -v OFS=, -F, '{ $4 = strftime("%c", ts - NR * 60) ; print $0 }' | tac
a,b,c,lun.  3 oct. 2016 15:32:29
a1,b1,c1,lun.  3 oct. 2016 15:33:29
a2,b2,c2,lun.  3 oct. 2016 15:34:29
```

Comment: And if you're using an operating system that doesn't include `tac` (like FreeBSD or OS X or Solaris or AIX, etc), check your `tail` command for a `-r` option. And if that fails, you can get similar results (assuming you have memory to hold the files) with `awk '{L[i++]=$0} END {for(j=i-1;j>=0;)print L[j--]}'`.

Answer (score 0):

This Gnu awk script first gets the current timestamp (epoch time), after the first iteration remembers `NR` of the file and on the second iteration updates the timestamps:

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{ts=strftime("%s")} NR==FNR{nr=NR; next}{$1=ts-(nr-FNR)*60} 1' file file
1455840000 76.357 899.500 326.717 8.000
1455840060 76.490 899.650 326.150 8.000
```

For compatibility with all awks—including Gnu awk—replace `BEGIN{}` block above with

`BEGIN{"date +'%s'"|getline ts}`

Comment: The `strftime()` function is part of GNU awk, but not other variants that I'm aware of.